# Set custom data-source for Angular Material Table in Angular 7

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

***P.S: I am new to Angular as well as to JS.***

In my new angular 7 project, i have a *Material Data Table* component. From a REST API, after making a `GET` call, i am able to populate an array of required object. It all happens in the component's `ngOnInit` method. (Not including the code, as it's irrelevant).

My question is, how do i bind the array to the `dataSource` of the data-table? In the data-table's HTML, i have, at the top :

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort aria-label="Elements">
  ....
  ....
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{row.id}}</td>
</...>
```

In the `..DataSource.ts` file, i have some properties and the `connect`, `disconnect` methods defined as follows:

```
export class TestTableItem {
 id: number; 
}

export class TestTableDataSource extends DataSource<TestTableItem> {
paginator: MatPaginator;
sort: MatSort;

  constructor(private TestArray: any[]) {
   super();
  }

  connect(collections: CollectionViewer): Observable<TestTableItem[]> {
    return observableOf<TestTableItem[]>(this.TestArray);
  }

  disconnect() {}
```

In the `component.ts`, i have the `dataSource` property declared, and as mentioned above, i am populating the array in the `ngOnInit()` method, as follows :

```
 private myCollection: TestTableItem[] = [];

 dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.myCollection);

 ngOnInit() {

  ...
  //adding new item to myCollection
 }
```

So, finally, how do i bind the array to the table? I tried to pass `new TestTableDataSource(this.myCollection);` to `this.dataSource`, in the `ngOnInIt` method, but it fails as `dataSource` and `TestTableDataSource` are of different types.

Not sure if i was able to put the words properly, but i hope readers would get my point. Any indication would be appreciated.

**UPDATE**

If i define `dataSource` as `TestTableDataSource`, as follows :

```
dataSource: TestTableDataSource;
```

The code works fine. However, the table remains empty. What's interesting is, making this change also removes all the columns of the table. The table becomes entirely blank. Why would the happen even when `myCollection` wasn't empty ?

Comment: What is the purpose of `TestTableDataSource`? I think it is not needed. What you want is to bind returned array from Rest API to table's datasource. Am I right? If yes, then on `ngOnInit` when array from your api is populated(let's call it myArr), you only have to initialize table's datasource from this array, like this  `this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(myArr);`

Comment: @leopal, and you're absolutely right! I would suggest you to add it as an answer. Thanks man!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no need to extend `DataSource` for binding the array returned from the REST API to mat table's datasource.

What I suggest is:

- to completely remove `TestTableDataSource` class
- on `ngOnInit` when array from your api is populated(let's call it `myArr`), you only have to initialize table's datasource from this array, like this`this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(myArr);`

After this, your array contents will be rendered as mat table's data.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't need pagination, sorting or filtering, then @leopal's answer will be ok.  If you you *do* need these features, then check out the *Angular Material* blog entry:
[Angular Material Data Table: A Complete Example (Server Pagination, Filtering, Sorting)](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-material-data-table/).

It's very complete and well explained - and too long to cover even the highlights here.  The one gap I'm seeing is how to update the total length of the paginator after applying a filter ... below is my working code.

Page:

```
export class Page<T> extends Array<T> {
    public static readonly DEFAULT_PAGE_SIZE: number = 10;

    pageIndex: number;
    pageSize: number;
    totalCount: number;

    constructor( pgIx?: number, pgSize?: number, tot?: number, items?: T[] )
    {
        super();
        this.pageIndex = pgIx ? pgIx : 0;
        this.pageSize = pgSize ? pgSize : 0;
        this.totalCount = tot ? tot : 0;
        if ( items && items.length > 0 ) {
            this.push( ...items );
        }
    }
}
```

table state:

```
import { Observable, BehaviorSubject, Observer } from "rxjs";
import { map, catchError, finalize,
         debounceTime, distinctUntilChanged, startWith, tap, delay 
       } from "rxjs/operators";

import { CollectionViewer, DataSource } from "@angular/cdk/collections";
import { MatPaginator }                 from '@angular/material';

import { MyError } from '../model/error';
import { Page } from '../model/page';

export class MyTableState<T> implements DataSource<T>, Observer<Page<T>> 
{
    private items = new BehaviorSubject<Page<T>>( new Page<T>() );
    private loading = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
    private err = new BehaviorSubject<DruidError>( new DruidError(0, '') );
    
    protected paginator: MatPaginator;

    items$ = this.items.asObservable();
    loading$ = this.loading.asObservable();
    error$ = this.err.asObservable();
    
    closed = false;
    
    constructor( protected itemType: string ) {
    }
    
    haveError() : boolean {
        const derr = this.err.getValue();
        if ( derr && (derr.status !== 0 || derr.message) ) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    errorStatus() : number {
        const derr = this.err.getValue();
        if ( derr ) {
            return derr.status;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    errorMessage() : string {
        const derr = this.err.getValue();
        if ( derr ) {
            return derr.message;
        }
        return '';
    }

    noResults() : boolean {
        const results = this.items.getValue();
        return !results || results.length == 0;
    }

    isLoading() : Observable<boolean> {
        return this.loading$;
    }

    totalCount() : number {
        const cnt = this.items.getValue();
        return ( cnt ? cnt.totalCount : 0 );
    }

    next( results: Page<T> ) : void {
        console.debug( "Found items: ", this.itemType, results );
        if ( this.paginator ) {
            this.paginator.length = results.totalCount;
        }
        this.items.next( results );
    }
    error( errr: any ) : void {
        console.error( "Error loading items: ", this.itemType, errr );
        this.err.next( errr );
    }
    complete() : void {
        console.debug( "Done loading items.", this.itemType );
        this.loading.next( false );
    }

    addItem( item: T ) : void {
        this.items.value.unshift( item );
    }

    connect( collectionViewer: CollectionViewer ) : Observable<Page<T>> {
        this.closed = false;
        return this.items$;
    }

    disconnect( collectionViewer: CollectionViewer ): void {
        this.closed = true;
        this.items.complete();
        this.loading.complete();
        this.err.complete();
    }
    
    protected preLoad() : void {
        this.err.next( new DruidError(0,'') );
        this.loading.next( true );
    }

    setPaginator( pgntr: MatPaginator ) : void {
        this.paginator = pgntr;
    }

    /* In a derived class implement this and call it from your containing 
     * components in response to filter input, etc.
    loadXyzs( offset: number = 0, limit: number = 10, predicates?: any ) : void
    {
        this.preLoad();

        this.xyzService
            .searchXyzs( offset, limit, predicates )
            .subscribe( this );
    }*/  
};
```

Answer (score -2):

You are creating different mat-tables

You can get a reference to your mat-table rendered in your HTML with a @ViewChild directive

```
@ViewChild('matTable') matTable: MatTable;

ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.matTable.data = yourData;
}
```

Or you can use the mat-table dataSource input in your HTML:

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="yourDataSource">
 // Your HTML
</table
```

Then changeDetection will do the rest for you